# Using useState hook in useEffect on history.listen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am having some troubles with `useState` when listening to `history` changes in `useEffect`.

When the `pathname` changes, `setState` is initiated but then the `state` is added back.

For example, I have a `flag` component that collects groups of notifications, but on the `pathname` change, I want all flags to be dismissed and removed from `state`.

**The flag component**

```
const PageFlag = ({ history }: InterfaceProps) => {
const { contextData, dismissFlag, dismissAllFlags } = useContext(GlobalConsumer);

  useEffect(() => {
    history.listen(() => {
      dismissAllFlags();
    });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <FlagGroup onDismissed={dismissFlag}>
        {contextData.flags.map((flag, index) => (
          <Flag key={index} {...flag} />
        ))}
      </FlagGroup>
    </>
  );
};
```

History prop is used from `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'`

The state and function for `dismissAllFlags` is shown in a `createContext` component as

```
const DefaultState: InterfaceState = {
  otherStateExample: false,
  flags: []
};

export const GlobalConsumer = createContext({
  contextData: DefaultState,
  addFlag: (flagData: any) => {},
  dismissFlag: () => {},
  dismissAllFlags: () => {}
});

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }: InterfaceProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<InterfaceState>({
    ...DefaultState
  });

  return (
    <GlobalConsumer.Provider
      value={{
        contextData: state,
        addFlag: (flagData: any) => {
          setState({ ...state, flags: [flagData].concat(state.flags) });
        },
        dismissFlag: () => {
          setState({ ...state, flags: state.flags.slice(1) });
        },
        dismissAllFlags: () => {
          setState({ ...state, flags: [] });
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalConsumer.Provider>
  );
};
```

The problem arises, where on `pathname` change, `dismissAllFlags` uses `setState` to set `flags` as `[]` but then adds back the previous state with the `flags`.

How can I remove all `flags` but remember the current `state` for other `items`?

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox?

Comment: It seems that your `GlobalProvider` could get unmounted in-between `pathname` changes along with its default state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the second input parameter on `useEffect()`, which is going to cause the listener to be readded on every render.

It should look like this, note you also should not need the inner function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  history.listen(dismissAllFlags)
}, []);
```

Comment: history should be a dependency

Comment: Whilst technically correct, the history object never changes, so their is no advantage in checking for something that never happens

Comment: Does the code above also unMount the history.listen? This isnt happening on my end.

Comment: Nope, you would need to return an unmount function from the effect

Comment: Don't you need a `return` here?

Comment: @NikolaMihajlović no, because you don’t need a clean up function on this hook, as it never ends

Comment: It should clean-up when the component is unmounted.

Answer (score 3):

We use it like this:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
    history.listen(() => setIsOpen(false));
  }, [history]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If I understand what your asking is this:**

> You would like to set the flags to an empty array without have to add the previous values using the spread method that you are currently doing `{...state, flags: []}`.

Well, this is not possible using `useState` and you should be cautions with nested state objects as cloning can becoming expensive with larger objects. *Maybe that is what your trying to avoid here*.

Even if you switch to `useReducer` you would still end up prop spreading for the state.

Perhaps you should just have flags as its own state `const [flags, setFlags] = useState([])` or look into [immutable-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Moreover,
Try to respect `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` otherwives funny things can start happening. If no deps then at least give your hook an empty array to ensure it is performed once.